# Vaadin ComboBox: clear input text on click

Tags: combobox, vaadin

I want a filterable combobox. When I click on the input text, the cursor appears so I can insert some characters into the text.

As typing into the input box is supposed to filter the items in the combobox, the previous text is no longer needed. I want either to:

1. clear the input text
2. select all the text (so when I start typing, the
   text is cleared) - according to http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/7116 this is not possible

Comment: I think you will have to extend the component and "onfocus" event set the value to null.

Comment: Actually, I can do that without extending with `addListener(new FocusListener(){..})`, but the problem is, how to set that value to null... `setValue(null)` don't work

Comment: You have set Immediate to true ?

Comment: Yes, I call `.setImmediate(true)`. But `.setImmediate(false)` didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I have test this on vaadin textfields, it should work for combos too.
You can clear the text on the input capturing the focus event, as in the comments, but instead of using null, use the empty string "", the change will not be seen until you call requestRepaint on the component.

```
       input.addListener(new FieldEvents.FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focus(FocusEvent event) {
                input.setValue("");
                input.requestRepaint();
            }
        });
```

However for this to work you has to lose the focus and gain it again, playing with the valueChange event (override, etc) could be better.

Comment: there is no `requestReoaint()` for combobox. So how is it possible for the combobox?